# Docker expose link to host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I am using a **docker-compose.yml** file for an application service and a database service:

```
version: '2'
services:

   app-service:
     image: app-image
     container_name: app-container
     ports:
       - "5000:5000"
     networks:
       - my-network
     links:
       - db-service

   db-service:
     image: db-image
     container_name: db-container
     ports:
       - "5432:5432"
     networks:
       - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

The application service connects to the database using a connection string with the **db-service** as host:

```
"User ID=postgres;Password=password;Host=db-service;Port=5432;Database=my-table;Pooling=true;"
```

That works fine on the running app container but I also need to access the database using the same connection string from my host machine. *(for database migrations during development)*

- I thought about adding a route to my host machine:
  **db-service -> localhost** But this is not a good solution since it     depends on the host operating system.
- I tried to use **localhost** in the connection string since my host machine then connects to the database container. But obviously the application container will not connect any more.
- I also played around with **network_mode** settings and network **driver** in the compose file but had no luck with that.

How can I use the same hostname in a container like in my host machine?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could use the same connection string for both your app-service and your host would be to update your host's `/etc/hosts` file with:

```
127.0.0.1 db-service
```

(or use your  if you're running on Docker machine)

But this solution may not be the cleanest one.
The best one would, IMO, be not to use the same connection string.